# Get MRTG to run as Windows Service

Tags: windows-server-2012, mrtg

We just installed mrtg on our Windows Server 2012 and I am having trouble getting it to run as a service.  [I'm following the guide here](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-nt-guide.en.html), but am still stuck.

First, if I run mrtg manually, whilst specifying a config file, it does work and does generate graphs.

But for the service, I placed the files `srvany.exe` and `instsrv.exe` in `c:\mrtg\bin`  (I removed the version number from the directory name, so it's all located now at `c:\mrtg`).

```
instsrv MRTG c:\mrtg\bin\srvany.exe
```

And I merged the regedit file into the registry and I can see the keys are there if I go and look.  You can see from the path to Perl that I've installed the 64 bit version of Perl.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MRTG-PA500\Parameters]
 "Application"="c:\\perl64\\bin\\wperl.exe"
 "AppParameters"="c:\\mrtg\\bin\\mrtg --logging=eventlog c:\\mrtg\\bin\\mrtg-MyDevice.cfg"
 "AppDirectory"="c:\\mrtg\\bin\\"
```

Now, after I do all of this, the service is indeed, created, but when I try to start it, it starts and stops.

So I created a domain account for the service and assigned it to the service and gave read/write/modify rights to the mrtg directory and it's web directory, but it still won't start.

What am I missing?

**[update]**

Also, if I use the commandline equivalent to what is set in the reg entry, then I get some weirdness.

```
c:\mrtg\bin>perl mrtg --logging=eventlog mrtg-mydevice.cfg
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 73.
Argument "Started mrtg with config 'mrtg-mydevice.cfg'\n" isn't numeric in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 46.
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 199. Argument "WARN" isn't numeric in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 199.
Daemonizing MRTG ...
Do Not close this window. Or MRTG will die
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 73.
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 199. Argument "WARN" isn't numeric in subroutine entry at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/EventLog.pm line 199.
```

**[update]**

I [just found this](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html), which states that svrany.exe is not really fit for Windows 7 (or Server 2012 after that).  I know some of the links on the mrtg site are pretty old.  Maybe I just can't use `srvany`?

But I think I probably have some configuration issue.

Comment: OK, you don't want to hear this. But....why are you trying to torture yourself so much by trying to get this running on a Windows server? There's nothing wrong with windows, but MRTG is a unix program. Fire up a linux/BSD system for it, for pete's sake. You'll have it working in 10 minutes.

Comment: @EEAA You are right!  That's not really what I want to hear.  I understand MRTG is originally a unix program, but there is a version for Windows, and it works just fine.  My problem here I see is getting it to run as a service.  Okay, so if I can't ever figure this out, I'll do it in linux; but until then I am in need of the torture.

Answer (score 1):

Okay!  The problem was that srvany.exe won't work right on newer models of Windows.  But [nssm.exe](http://nssm.cc) will!  `nssm` stands for *non-sucking-service-manager* - nifty name!

So I created a batchfile with this in it.

```
::Monday, June 15, 2015
::http://nssm.cc/download
::Apparently, srvany.exe doesn't work right on newer Windows, so I got a 64bit nssm (non-sucking service manager) to put in its place.
::commandline directions: http://nssm.cc/commands

nssm install mrtg wperl "mrtg --logging=eventlog mrtg-mydevice.cfg"
nssm set mrtg AppDirectory c:\mrtg\bin
nssm set mrtg displayname mrtg
nssm set mrtg description "MRTG wPerl Service"
nssm set mrtg start service_auto_start
nssm start mrtg
```

Once I did this, the service started right up.  Now I can see `nssm.exe` and `wperl` (with it's proper commandline) running in the processes list.  And I can modify the service by modifying the batch script.

So now you can stop it with `nssm stop mrtg`

and start it with `nssm start mrtg`

(or you can manage other windows services, too, if you like)